# python scipy not installed in windows 8.1

Tags: python, scipy

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install scipy
    Collecting scipy
      Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
    Installing collected packages: scipy
      Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
        Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
    , tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\vijay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-24kqagu2\
    \scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repl
    ace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --rec
    ord C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-_g_ss4a3-record\install-record.txt --s
    ingle-version-externally-managed --compile:

        Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
        with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

          - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                   release)
          - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\
    \libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python3
    4\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarni
    ng: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\a
    tlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
          pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarnin
    g:
            Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
            the ATLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\
    \libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarnin
    g:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarnin
    g:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE

        Running from scipy source directory.
        non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-24kqagu2\scipy\setup.py"
    , line 416, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-24kqagu2\scipy\setup.py"
    , line 412, in setup_package
            setup(**metadata)
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in
     setup
            config = configuration()
          File "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-24kqagu2\scipy\setup.py"
    , line 336, in configuration
            config.add_subpackage('scipy')
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
    01, in add_subpackage
            caller_level = 2)
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
    0, in get_subpackage
            caller_level = caller_level + 1)
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
    7, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
            config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
          File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
            config.add_subpackage('linalg')
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
    01, in add_subpackage
            caller_level = 2)
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
    0, in get_subpackage
            caller_level = caller_level + 1)
          File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
    7, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
            config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
          File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
            raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
        numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
        ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
    \Users\\vijay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-24kqagu2\\scipy\\setup.py';f=geta
    ttr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clos
    e();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\vijay\AppDa
    ta\Local\Temp\pip-_g_ss4a3-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally
    -managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Tem
    p\pip-build-24kqagu2\scipy\`enter code here`
```

Comment: Any one please help me,how to resolve the python scipy

Comment: Learn how to ask question on StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are tons of questions here with the problem scipy + windows. Search for these. The answers are mostly the same. Even the official docs will tell you: don't use pip for scipy install on windows, except you are an expert (in regards to building software on windows).